# VS2017 solution with common output directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution with 25+ projects. I set the build output directory of all projects to the same common directory _BIN. Everything works fine when building individual projects. When building all projects at the same time *sometimes* I get the warning

Could not copy "{project name}\Languages\ENGLISH.cre" to ".._BIN\Debug\Languages\ENGLISH.cre". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file '.._BIN\Debug\Languages\ENGLISH.cre' because it is being used by another process.

This uses to go away if I retry. I understand that this must be a caching issue or something. Is there any way to "fix" this, by, for example forcing VS to build all projects sequentially first and wait until the previous project has been fully built before building the next one?

I have noticed that the conflict takes place almost always (but not limited to)  with some text files (ENGLISH.cre, SPANISH.cre, etc) that I have as "Copy always" in the build options of one project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number of parallel project builds to 1, forcing VS to only build one project at a time, although it might be horribly slow depending on your projects:

`Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > Maximum number of parallel project builds`